# What happens if a Cassandra node runs out of disk space during a compaction?

Tags: database, cassandra

We had a Cassandra node that received some very large writes; Each was around 2.9MB and written ~200 times. Normally, each node on our cluster sits around 800GB usage; About half of 1.5TB space on our EC2 instances.

When that node did it's compaction, the process went on much longer than normal and the disk usage nearly hit the 1.5TB limit. The compaction went on for over 2 days and we just got lucky that it finished at a little over 1.4TB.

What happens if a node runs out of disk space during a compaction? Can it recover? Does it clean itself up and retry? Or is the node left full and need to be decommissioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends, it can change from version to version and configuration. If there's enough space for its compaction to complete it will, and hopefully depending on data model, go back down. Some compaction strategies require more ([SizeTieredCompactionStrategy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_configure_compaction_t.html#task_ds_cwj_1jv_dk__compact-strategy) STCS ~50%) or less ([LeveledCompactionStrategy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_configure_compaction_t.html#task_ds_cwj_1jv_dk__compact-strategy) LCS ~80%) free space to operate "safely". Your data model can affect it significantly.

What you can expect if you actually run out of disk though is either:

- the [disk failure policy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__disk_failure_policy) kicks in which can either turn off C* or ignore it.
- An uncaught IOException on the compaction executor, which kills the thread. Eventually if this keeps up all compaction threads will be dead and you will be in a lot of trouble. this shouldn't happen, but does due to misc bugs which is very version specific.